# Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?

Tags: java, browser, cross-platform

Is there a way to embed a browser in Java? more specifically, is there a library that can emulate a browser?

Comment: [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) library provides Swing/JavaFX lightweight component based on the latest Chromium engine. The web pages are rendered by Chromium engine off-screen and displayed in the lightweight Swing/JavaFX component. It's very [easy to use](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012864-quick-start-guide-for-swing-developers). It's free for Open-Source and Academic projects.

Comment: i thought, it is commercial. I mean how could you get the free license  @Vladimir ?

Comment: In the evaluation form at https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser#evaluate, select Open-Source or Academic. You will see short explanation: The evaluation licence will not work after this time. If you are doing an open source project, you can request a permanent licence via the link provided in the email you will receive. So, once you request evaluation, you will get an email you can write to to request a free license for open-source project.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since JavaFX 2.0 you can use now [webview](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)

[image]

Comment: A howto is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8413289/4857

Comment: An alternative JavaFX library is JxBrowser with BrowserView component:  http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser

Comment: WebView has some performance issues, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762979/performance-of-webview-in-javafx

Comment: shitty thing ever possible. worst performance, javascript seldom works, unwanted behavior. Can never be used in any good project

Comment: Just tried out WebView (Jan 9, 2021), and it is now very performant! (on macOS)   Very nice overall and I think I will be making GUIs via this method (also lets me embed nice javascript widgets)

Answer (score 22):

I believe JWebPane is going to be the official way to embed a browser into a java app. Its based on the open sourced engine - WebKit, which is used in Apples Safari and Googles Chrome browsers.See [this blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2008/05/introducing_jwe.html) for details.

Comment: JWebPane shows no signs of activity/life... However mozswing seems to work pretty well. I tried the JNLP download version and it the page renders well. Memory usage is a high, but support for web standards is good as it is based on the Mozilla browser. Available at http://confluence.concord.org/display/MZSW/Home

Comment: As of april 2010, this is not possible. It seems JWebPane is vaporware :(

Comment: April 2011, almost, still no sign, just like JMF too, for video mission is like mission impossible. Firefox 4 is launched yesterday.

Comment: **Update** JWebPane changed into WebView in JavaFX 2.0 ( the libraries series ) See: http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm  for a sample screenshot of it running see: http://www.javamexico.org/blogs/oscarryz/webview_en_javafx ( not written in Java though but in a experimental JVM language )

Comment: Is WebView in JavaFX truly standalone cross platform or does it depend on any platform specific native components? More importantly, how does it stack up to rendering pages? It is powered by WebKit but is this as close to having a real browser when it comes to rendering websites?

Comment: may 2014.. is it possible now?

Comment: october 2015, guys? are you there?

Comment: it is possible now. Altough i am having problem with the sites using jquerry .

Answer (score 9):

You could use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt) for your GUI.  Its Browser control allows you to embed IE, Mozilla or Safari (depending on the platform you're running in) with little pain.

Comment: The return values of browser.evaluate() are limited to a view types. The JavaFx WebEngine can handle all kinds of return types by wrapping the return value in JSObject.

Answer (score 9):

You may try this: https://jdic.dev.java.net/

[image]
<sub>(source: [java.net](https://jdic.dev.java.net/resource/browser.jpg))</sub>

Or this: http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp

[image]
<sub>(source: [lobobrowser.org](http://lobobrowser.org/images/google-news.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Its very good to have something atleast. But its very slow and the graphics is very bad compared to Chrome or Firefox 4

Comment: No update for Lobo for 2 years

Comment: @OzhanDuz any details about JDIC issues? I like the approach, but haven't used it myself yet.

Comment: Stay away from JDIC, its not multiplatform, i am not sure but development might be stopped or not active. Use DJ Native Swing, you will get regular updates, better api and more stable.

Answer (score 3):

By far the most robust embeddable browser I am familiar with is the one in SWT.
In fact, it is so flexible that the JavaDoc hover you can see in Eclipse is actually a browser, and the JavaDoc view actually supports things like animation!

The only risk with using SWT is that there are different versions of the SWT library for different platforms. I'm not sure if there is a singl jar you could include to cover everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at 
https://xhtmlrenderer.dev.java.net/

Comment: Now known as the Flying Saucer, http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

Answer (score 3):

[JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/) has not been mentionned yet. It embed either Mozilla Firefox (Gecko), Apple Safari (WebKit) or Internet Explorer. [Programmer's Guide](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/docs/JxBrowser-PGuide.html)

Comment: Also [JExplorer](http://www.teamdev.com/jexplorer/) is a cheaper solution by TeamDev if you do not need a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Starting from 4.0 version JxBrowser integrates with Chromium engine.

Comment: I've been looking for a real answer to this question for years, and JxBrowser version 4 is really a game changer. It is exactly what you'd hope a swing browser component would be.

Comment: Now [JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) allows embedding Google Chromium engine into Java Swing/JavaFX applications. It supports two rendering modes: lightweight (off-screen) and heavyweight (GPU-accelerated). It's free for Open-Source projects.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the JWebBrowser from DJ Native Swing: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully opened a browser from Java using [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/).  You can find [code examples](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#browser) of how to use SWT to open a Browser window.  It's very easy to do.

Comment: The return values of browser.evaluate() are limited to a view types. The JavaFx WebEngine can handle all kinds of return types by wrapping the return value in JSObject

Answer (score 2):

You can embed a browser in a Swing/AWT GUI using the [JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net/#demos) API. [I don't see any mention of OS X](https://jdic.dev.java.net/documentation/README.html#System%20Requirements), so it may not be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Webrenderer](http://www.webrenderer.com/products/swing/product/) or [Ice Browser](http://www.icesoft.com/products/icebrowser.html)

Comment: Ice Browser is not actually sold anymore, the product has reached End of Life

Answer (score 1):

If you need a pure Java solution then you can try [JWebEngine](http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/jwebengine). It render HTML 4 very good. You can use it in an applet, Java webstart and on any platform. The using is very simple.

Comment: However, it is not an open source solution. It might not fit all needs.

Comment: Open source was not a requirement of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `JEditorPane`, it doesn't interpret advanced HTML, nor Javascript, nor advanced CSS, but you can write that part yourself, called the `EditorKit`. That is the class/object that is consulted by the JEditorPane or how it has to display its content.

I know its possible, because I tried and failed (:P), but it could be outdated or deprecated by now, I don't know.

Comment: JEditorPane only supports up to HTML 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) is an option for you. Specific to Java there is

javacef for SWT: https://github.com/wjywbs/javacef

java-cef for AWT: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef

Answer (score 0):

If you look at The Minecraft launcher (the old one), look through LoginForm or LauncherFrame, you may be able to find out that method. There is a tutorial by kippykip on youtube on how to decompile and edit it: [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_bh-c2nO7k)