# Is there any available library for displaying offline raster map in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, gis, raster, geotiff

As the title suggest, I'm looking for a library to display offline map in android.

---

### My Objective

I have a raster map in (Geo)Tiff format that I want to display.

---

### Similar Questions

[Android - offline, non-vector based, custom maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482206/android-offline-non-vector-based-custom-maps)

[Offline map using mapsforge in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645235/offline-map-using-mapsforge-in-android)

---

### What I've done

I looked and rerefined my search both in Google and here with mostly only mentioning vector map library, such as OSMDroid.

I also looked to [mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) with no luck because the osmosis only generate map from OSM data.

---

### What I know

I know that mobile GIS is not suitable to take large Tiff format right on. So I'm prepared to convert and recalibrate the map to whatever suitable format the library can take.

Well I remember there was a good library called GVSIG. Unfortunately right now it can't be found due to some problem with the trademark holder?

If you ever heard of an app called Locus, that is actually my objective. It can take any offline map sources both vector and raster one.

---

### Why don't you start your own?

Well, I'm not really good at it so that's why I'm looking a library in the first place.

And seriously, you don't want to see me leading one. It involves a lot of mess.

Comment: OSMDroid is not vector it is raster I would recommend a closer look.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response Ifor. It seems I can't find a way to convert my tiff file to osmdroid tile zip file. Anyway I think I'll mark my question as resolve to use OSMDroid. Perhaps you want to answer it and I'll accept it right away. As for my objective to load my tiff file to osmdroid I'll just ask another question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSMDroid is raster based not vector based.  For a raster based mapping library with offline support it dose a good job.  Converting you tiff to a suitable format may toke some work I don't know if MOAB will take a tiff input worth having a look though.

Comment: I try MOBAC and it only take online sources, still looking a way to convert it though but thanks anyway

Comment: If you need to spin your own there is a link to the file format in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094076/osmdroid-zip-how-to-add-custom-maps/9110391#9110391