# java android openlayers equivalent

Tags: java, android, openlayers

I am looking for a java library that can display map from different sources.
I saw a similar posts like

([Java equivalent of OpenLayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895653/java-equivalent-of-openlayers)).

but i am not so sure how its interact with the android interface.

also i need it to support a single picture source (no tiles lib) 
similar to http://jsfiddle.net/rdt2/N7dSu/37/.

basically i need something that support image source an `Google Maps` source

is anyone familiar with such a thing?

Comment: Well, there is the Google Maps Android library: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ which will, naturally, support a Google Maps source and adding a single tile would be easy in Android with the 2D drawing API. OpenLayers is designed to work on mobile devices, but in a browser, not with interactions with the Android SDK.

Comment: im familiar with Google api. what do  you mean by 2D drawing AP?

Comment: I was referring to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: i am not so sure how its going to work. maybe i wasn't so so clear but i want it to work exactly like the the demo in the link (navigation and zoom in/out). i am new in android developing so maybe its just me can please give me more details?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to run the app in a browser you can always fall back and deploy the OpenLayers browser application via PhoneGap to a native Android app.

http://phonegap.com/