# Embed a web browser within a java application

Tags: java, browser, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)

how can i embed a web browser within a java application?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of alternatives:

- [JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) - included in the JRE, but only renders simple HTML
- [JDIC](http://workshop.evolutionzone.com/2007/08/30/jdic-embedding-a-web-browser-in-java/) - open source, embeds native browser
- [ICEBrowser](http://www.icesoft.com/products/icebrowser.html) - commercial, renders the HTML in Java
- [WebRenderer](http://www.webrenderer.com) - commercial, embeds native browser in Java

And a few more that don't seem to be under active development.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the JWebBrowser from DJ Native Swing: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns

Comment: Seems nice (stunning demo), but is a bit harsh to port into netbeans module. Do you have a tip or an already built NBM ?

Comment: Yes this. I was hoping for something as well.

Comment: The DJ Native Swing distribution contains a "netbeans" subfolder with instructions to create modules.

Answer (score 1):

If you want pure java solution, try [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org).

Otherwise, you may use SWT / JRex or some other JNI-based product.

Answer (score 1):

[Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) is small and renders pretty well *regular* HTML pages

Answer (score 1):

If you need a pure Java solution then you can use [JWebEngine](http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/jwebengine). Its the best pure Java solution currently available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWT for this, here's a [simple example](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg38959.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got another one

[The Lobo Project](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) - Open Source

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mozswing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozswing). It works.