# CSS Styling with Swing

Tags: java, css, swing

How to introduce CSS style for various Swing components like `JButton`, `JPanel` etc. in a Swing application?

Comment: Here is an open source lbrary [that](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-css-engine/) helps to style swing components using custom css rules.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. The [HTML parser](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/bookmarks/) that some Swing components use does not even support most HTML tags; it does not support CSS at all.

If you need advanced HTML support in a Java app, you will have to use one of the [third-party components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/java-embedding-a-web-browser-pane) that [provide it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943927/embed-a-web-browser-within-a-java-application).

Comment: This is inaccurate. In my experience, using a <style> element in a <head> element after your <html> opening, you can put CSS rules. Note, however, that Swing support is CSS 1.0 at most - it looks like background will work, but overflow won't (which is quite a shame in my case...).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the various Swing properties to describe UI defaults that will be shared by all components - like fonts etc - but as Michael mentions; there's no way to do full `CSS`. For example:

```
FontUIResource f = new FontUIResource("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12)
UIManager.put("MenuBar.font", f); //javax.swing.UIManager
UIManager.put("Menu.font", f);
UIManager.put("RootPane.titleFont", f);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used javacss successfully in some projects. I dropped javafx support from it for my purpose and fixed a severe memory leak (there still maybe some more). I created a github project for that, since the license is gpl:

https://github.com/cyberbeat/java-css

Comment: Is this the same JavaCSS described in this article: [Styling Swing Components with Java CSS](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1390174)?

Comment: It IS the same, at least it seams so to me. The article references exactly the same packages and class names. This was the first blog introduction from the original author I think: https://community.oracle.com/blogs/enicholas/2008/07/17/introducing-java-css