# Can I use CSS for Java Swing?

Tags: java, css, swing

Is there any way to reuse my CSS in an application that uses Java Swing ?

Comment: You already have a CSS file you use for something else? A web page perhaps? What would you like to use CSS for? Just colors and font sizes or layout and behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I have CSS file that is used in my web application, but in my web application, i´m using one applet developed in swing. So, I want to know if exist possibilities of reuse my css.

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057137/css-with-swing

Comment: I don't know if we have something that parse the css style, but for Swing application I have been using [Miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), that is not a translation of css, but it follows most of patterns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/
Flying Saucer takes XML or XHTML and applies CSS 2.1-compliant stylesheets to it, in order to render to PDF (via iText), images, and on-screen using Swing or SWT

Answer (score 10):

Java swing generally isn't built to separate its controls from its presentation, but there is an open-source framework called [Jaxx](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/30/introducing-jaxx.html) that has been written that might help you.  With Jaxx you can do something like [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/03/style_swing_com.html):

```
<Application title='Calculator'>
  <style source='Calculator.css'/> //your style goes here...
  <script source='Calculator.script'/>
  <Table fill='both' id='table'>
<row>
  <cell columns='4'><JLabel id='display' text='0'/></cell>
</row>

<row>
  <cell columns='2'><JButton id='c' label='C' onActionPerformed='clear()' styleClass='clear'/></cell>      
  <cell><JButton id='ce'     label='CE' onActionPerformed='clearEntry()' styleClass='clear'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='equals' label='=' onActionPerformed='equal()' styleClass='operator'/></cell>
</row>

<row>
  <cell><JButton id='d7'   label='7' onActionPerformed='digit(7)' styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='d8'   label='8' onActionPerformed='digit(8)' styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='d9'   label='9' onActionPerformed='digit(9)' styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='plus' label='+' onActionPerformed='add()' styleClass='operator'/></cell>
</row>

<row> 
  <cell><JButton id='d4'       label='4' onActionPerformed='digit(4)'   styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='d5'       label='5' onActionPerformed='digit(5)'   styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='d6'       label='6' onActionPerformed='digit(6)'   styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='subtract' label='-' onActionPerformed='subtract()' styleClass='operator'/></cell>
</row>

<row>
  <cell><JButton id='d1'       label='1' onActionPerformed='digit(1)' styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='d2'       label='2' onActionPerformed='digit(2)' styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='d3'       label='3' onActionPerformed='digit(3)' styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='multiply' label='x' onActionPerformed='multiply()' styleClass='operator'/></cell>
</row>

<row>
  <cell><JButton id='d0'     label='0' onActionPerformed='digit(0)' styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='sign'   label='+/-' onActionPerformed='toggleSign()' styleClass='operator'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='dot'    label='.' onActionPerformed='dot()' styleClass='digit'/></cell>
  <cell><JButton id='divide' label='&#x00F7;' onActionPerformed='divide()' styleClass='operator'/></cell>
</row>
```

and then include a css file to style your components:

```
Application {
    lookAndFeel: system;
}
#display {
    background: #BCE5AD;
    opaque: true;
    horizontalAlignment: right;
    border: {BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED)};
    font-size: 22;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```