# Swing style with CSS

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have been doing some GUIs in Java. I know in other languages (like Python) you can create a CSS style sheet and load it into the program(pretty simple). But with Swing I have had to manually code the style for each individual component, which is tedious and hard to manage.

Is there a way, in Swing, that I can load an external style sheet, and use those styles for my components across my whole program?

I have already looked into "Look and Feel" as an option, but decided to go with CSS.

Comment: JavaFX 2 is full CSS-able and included up from Java7. Maybe time to go with it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing will be deprecated and [replaced by JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6) in the long run. If you are building a new application, why don't you look into [skinning JavaFX with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know is [java-universal-css-engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-css-engine/), but I don't know if it's maintained anymore, because the last commit was on Mar 25, 2012.

So, regarding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956934/java-swing-with-css), have a look at [JAXX](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/30/introducing-jaxx.html)