# Can you use CSS in Java form

Tags: java, css

I don’t know if it’s a logical question or not… I know that CSS For web designs But I would really like to know .. 
I have a button for example in Java (JButton).. and I want to apply a design to it or modify it with CSS .. Can this be done? If possible , how?

Comment: look at this question [Use CSS in Java Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372288/use-css-in-java-applications)

Comment: You used JavaFx

Comment: https://openjfx.io/