# How to set a CSS to be used by all jtooltips in my Java application?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, tooltip

Is there a way to define a global stylesheet that is used for all my `JToolTip`s throughout my application? If not, how can I define a stylesheet for a tooltip for a single component of which I only know that it is a swing component (`JComponent`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057137/css-with-swing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color for tooltip, there are several look and feel defaults properties with keys:

```
ToolTip.background
ToolTip.backgroundInactive
ToolTip.border
ToolTip.borderInactive
ToolTip.font
ToolTip.foreground
ToolTip.foregroundInactive
```

e.g. For set the new color for foreground

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.foreground",java.awt.Color.red);
```

e.g. in one application I have these defaults

```
ToolTip.background   =>     javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229]
ToolTip.backgroundInactive   =>     javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=238,g=238,b=238]
ToolTip.border   =>     javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$LineBorderUIResource@da18ac
ToolTip.borderInactive   =>     javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$LineBorderUIResource@8a0544
ToolTip.font     =>     javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=Dialog,name=Dialog,style=plain,size=12]
ToolTip.foreground   =>     sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51]
ToolTip.foregroundInactive   =>     javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=122,g=138,b=153]
```