# CSS on Java Swing from Java Code

Tags: java, css, swing, javafx

I am designing a eclipse plugin, where i use Components of Swing and JavaFx. In this I can apply CSS on JavaFX. But i could not apply CSS for Swing components. I was forced to use Swing component for some features of the plugin. So i would like to apply CSS for Swing components too. Is there any api that supports CSS on Swing component?

```
//This code applies css for javafx components
SwingJavaFxSample.class.getResource("samples.css").toExternalForm();
```

Please help me in applying css for Swing components too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956934/java-swing-with-css)

Comment: also similar: [css with swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057137/css-with-swing?)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the JavaFX CSS support on Swing controls so to me the question makes no sense. Let me also say that using 3 UI-Technologies together is not really a good idea you'll run into many threading issues (SWT & FX share the same event thread whereas Swing is on another one), ... .

What is the reason you still need Swing? JavaFX can be embedded directly into SWT.