# How to customize a JButton's interface using css

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

Is it a good idea to edit a JButton's interface by using  css? If no, please specify alternatives. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS on Java Swing from Java Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398178/css-on-java-swing-from-java-code)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to edit a JButton's interface by using CSS?

No.  While some Swing controls support HTML and simple styles, a button styled that way will lose the default disabled appearance.

> If no, please specify alternatives.

Adjust the [Pluggable Look and Feel](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/02/27/laf.html).