# How can I open an HTML page and show it in a text area?

Tags: java

How can I open an HTML page and show it in a text area? (If I choose the HTML file with the JFileChooser, how can I open that page and show it in the text area?)

```
URL url = new URL(String s);
JEditorPane pane = JEditorPane(url);
```

But how can I find the link of the HTML file for inserting as `s`, here!?

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: do you want the source of the html in the text area ?

Comment: I want to show the content of that html file in the text area not the source of that file

Comment: for example I have a html file in my computer and I want to show its content in the text area.How can I find the source of that file?

Comment: You get the file into a string... and you print it out.  I don't know anything about JEditorPane, so I won't make this an answer.  You should also specify whether or not the file will need any server-side processing done to it first, as that will affect whether or not you can just dump the file contents into your page.

Answer (score 1):

A TextArea is for displaying/editing text, not for showing formatted HTML.

[JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) supports HTML markup, but only a rather limited subset.

For full HTML support, you're going to need third-party components. Look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943927/embed-a-web-browser-within-a-java-application) for links.

Answer (score 0):

Format the HTML with a `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use any properly formatted URL a browser would use e.g.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239454/how-can-i-open-an-html-page-and-show-it-in-a-text-area
```

But then again Java is very keen on security and you might not be allowed to use certain URLs in your environment.

And like Michael Borgwardt said - the JEditorPane's support of HTML is very limited and some tags (i think <div> is one of them) as well as JavaScript are not supported.

For implementation of a simple browser have a look at this
[JEditorPane Tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html)