# web browser embedded into java

Tags: java, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)

I am working on an application where I have to embed a web browser with application. Any ideas on how to achieve it? Also will I be able to interact JavaScript from within the code?

Comment: JWebPane, wherever did you go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this post .... [Embed a web browser within a java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943927/embed-a-web-browser-within-a-java-application)

Answer (score 0):

check out Eclipse, it has an embedded browser which is configurable by the user (they support multiple browsers).

you can probably embed their browser even if you use an AWT based application using the AWT_SWT bridge if you are using Java swing application.

this [article](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3644196/Eclipse-Tip-Create-Rich-User-Interfaces-with-the-HTML-Browser-Widget.htm) may help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp)

> [Lobo] is an open source web browser that is
>   written completely in Java. Lobo is
>   being actively developed with the aim
>   to fully support HTML 4, Javascript
>   and CSS2. Lobo also supports direct
>   JavaFX rendering.

Answer (score 0):

For very simple pages, you can use the JEditorPane, which is in the Swing API: [see doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that embedding a real browser is your only option, if you need JavaScript capabily and AJAX etc. look at [JavaXPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaXPCOM) API in order to see how easily you can embed FireFox.  There is also [JDIC](http://pcquest.ciol.com/content/coding/2004/104090202.asp), that will allow you to embed IE in Windows environments. You will need some DLL files but the procedure is straight forward with both APIs and well documented.

Let's admit that JEditorPane is fine, but mainly for HTML you have control over. I use it only to render HTML help files into my application. Once you start visiting sites with it things start getting nasty.

Comment: Java 8 has a builtin javascript engine: Nashorn.  That's not an embedded browser, but it is at least javascript.