# Embed .swf file to my Jframe

Tags: java, flash, jframe

I'm having a problem in adding my swf file to my jframe. They say that i should try the JFlashplayer but it is only a trial one. Can you give me some sample code for this?

Comment: What, for using the full JFlashPlayer API?  Pay the money for the full version & I guess the authors will provide support.

Comment: is there any alternative code aside from using the JFlashPlayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my flash player adapted from the example on their website. BCFrame is essentially a JInternalFrame. You can have it extend whatever. It will need slight modification to work, but should be strait forward. You can rip out anything that doesnt exist.

Other possible solutions are:
jffmpeg - do a search for it
http://www.humatic.de/htools/dsj/samplecode.php?WebM.java
http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/
http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/08/20/flash_in_java/

```
package Components.FlashPlayer;

import Components.BCFrame;
import GUI.BCApp.DataTypeEnum;
import Logging.LogRunner;
import Properties.Basic.FlashPlayer_Prop;
import XMLProcessing.Helpers.XMLActionInfoHolder;
import XMLProcessing.XMLUtilities;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import java.io.*;

// import the JFlashPlayer package
import com.jpackages.jflashplayer.*;
import java.net.URL;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

/**
 * This class plays a flash video.
 * Create with help from: http://www.jpackages.com/jflashplayer , see the website
 * for a larger example of how to do more things with this code. I kind of modified
 * this to fit the current needs of the project. This works in conjunction with
 * dlls that need to go in the win32 folder. For linux/mac, look into the Apple
 * Java Quicktime API
 * @author dvargo
 */
public class FlashPlayer extends BCFrame implements FlashPanelListener {

    /**
     * handle to a FlashPanel instance
     */
    FlashPanel flashPanel;
    final Label currentFrameLabel = new Label("Frame: N/A");
    final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    JButton playButton,stopButton,forwardButton,rewindButton,backButton;
    JCheckBox loopCheckBox;
    private boolean isMovieSet = false;
    FrameMonitorThread fmt;
    boolean loop = false;
    boolean playOnStart = true;




    public enum Actions
    {
        Loop,
        Stop,
        Play
    }

    /**
     * Defualt constructor
     */
    public FlashPlayer()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Sets FlashPlayer to defualt size
     * @param x X position for the player
     * @param y Y position for the player
     * @param mainWindow Reference to the main window
     */
    public FlashPlayer(int x, int y, GUI.Window mainWindow) {
        this(x, y, 600, 400, mainWindow);
    }

    /**
     * Full consturtor
     * @param x X position for this player
     * @param y Y position for this player
     * @param w Width of the player
     * @param h Height of the player
     * @param mainWindow reference to the main window
     */
    public FlashPlayer(int x, int y, int w, int h, GUI.Window mainWindow) {
        super(x, y, w, h, mainWindow);
        initComponents();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        createButtons();
        addCurrCompSetter(flashPanel,progressBar,currentFrameLabel,playButton,stopButton,forwardButton,rewindButton,loopCheckBox,backButton);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //                           
    private void initComponents() {

        videoPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        videoPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout videoPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(videoPanel);
        videoPanel.setLayout(videoPanelLayout);
        videoPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            videoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 381, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        videoPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            videoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 247, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(videoPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(videoPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }//                         

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel videoPanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   




    /**
     * FlashPanelListener event method which receives FSCommand Flash events.
     *
     * You should use ExternalInterface.call instead of FSCommand
     * with the latest ActionScript version.  Older ActionScript versions
     * will only have access to FSCommand.
     */
    public void FSCommand(String command, String arg) {
        System.out.println("FlashPlayer (ignoring): FSCommand event received: " + command + " " + arg);
    }

    private void creatFlashPlayerWorker()
    {
         // add the FlashPanel to the frame
        this.getContentPane().add(flashPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        // specify the object for Flash ExternalInterface.call events to search for the called method on
        flashPanel.setFlashCallObject(this);

        // specify the FlashPanelListener in case a movie is using the older FSCommand event
        flashPanel.addFlashPanelListener(this);

        // specify variables for a flash movie which are available from the start of the
        // movie as long as this is called before the FlashPanel is visible
        flashPanel.setVariables("myGreeting=hi&myNumber=1&myVar=good%20job");

        isMovieSet = true;
        centerAndDisplay();
        fmt = new FrameMonitorThread(flashPanel);
        fmt.start();
        revalidate();
        if(!playOnStart)
        {
            stop();
        }
        setLoop(loop);
    }

    /**
     * Create a FlashPanel instance and add it to the frame
     */
    public void createFlashPanel(String url) {
        // install Flash 10 if Flash 6 or greater is not present
        //FlashPanel.installFlash("6");

        dataSource = dataSource.url;
        setData("Path",url.toString());
        String flashVersionRequired = "9";
        try
        { 
            FlashPanel.setRequiredFlashVersion(flashVersionRequired);
            flashPanel = new FlashPanel(new URL(url));//new File(flashFilePath));
        } 
        catch (JFlashLibraryLoadFailedException e)
        {
            exitError("A required library (DLL) is missing or damaged.");
        } 
        catch(JFlashInvalidFlashException e)
        {
            exitError("Required version " + flashVersionRequired + " of Flash is not installed. ");
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exitError("Something went wrong!\n" + e.toString());
        }

        creatFlashPlayerWorker();

    }

     /**
     * Create a FlashPanel instance and add it to the frame
     */
    public void createFlashPanel(File file) {
        // install Flash 10 if Flash 6 or greater is not present
        //FlashPanel.installFlash("6");

        //http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/SWF/flash_adpcm_testfiles/stereo_22.swf

        dataSource = dataSource.file;
        setData("Path",file.getAbsolutePath());
        String flashVersionRequired = "9";
        try
        {
            FlashPanel.setRequiredFlashVersion(flashVersionRequired);
            flashPanel = new FlashPanel(file);//new File(flashFilePath));
        }
        catch (JFlashLibraryLoadFailedException e)
        {
            exitError("A required library (DLL) is missing or damaged.");
        }
        catch(JFlashInvalidFlashException e)
        {
            exitError("Required version " + flashVersionRequired + " of Flash is not installed. ");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exitError("Something went wrong!\n" + e.toString());
        }

        creatFlashPlayerWorker();
    }


    public boolean isMovieSet()
    {
        return isMovieSet;
    }

    public boolean isPlayOnStart()
    {
        return playOnStart;
    }

    public boolean isLoop()
    {
        return loop;
    }

    public void setPlayOnStart(boolean dis)
    {
        playOnStart = dis;
    }
    public void setIsLoop(boolean dis)
    {
        loop = dis;
    }



    /**
     * Select a different SWF file at remote url
     */
    public void setMovie(URL url)
    {
        if(!isMovieSet)
        {
            createFlashPanel(url.toString());
            return;
        }
        setData("Path",url.toString());
        dataSource = dataSource.url;
        flashPanel.setMovie(url);
    }

    /**
     * Select a different SWF file at remote url
     */
    public void setMovie(String url)
    {
        if(!isMovieSet)
        {
            createFlashPanel(url);
            return;
        }
        setData("Path",url);
        dataSource = dataSource.url;
        try
        {
            flashPanel.setMovie(new URL(url));
            revalidate();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LogRunner.dialogMessage(this.getClass(),"Could not play Flash Movie at " + url);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Select a different SWF file on local machine
     */
    public void setMovie(File file)
    {

        setData("Path",file.getAbsolutePath()); //setting this to absolute path might cause a problem
        dataSource = dataSource.file;
        try
        {
            if(isMovieSet)
            {
                flashPanel.setMovie(file);
            }
            else
            {
                createFlashPanel(file);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           LogRunner.dialogMessage(this.getClass(),"Could not play Flash Movie at " + file);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to play.
     */
    public void play()
    {
        flashPanel.play();
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to stop playing.
     */
    public void stop()
    {
        flashPanel.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to go back one frame.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     */
    public void rewind()
    {
        rewind(1);
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to go back x number of frames.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     * @param numberOfFrames The number of frames to rewind
     */
    public void rewind(int numberOfFrames)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
        {
            flashPanel.back();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to go forward 1 frame.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     */
    public void forward()
    {
        forward(1);
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to go forward x number of frame.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     */
    public void forward(int numberOfFrames)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
        {
            flashPanel.forward();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to rewind to the first frame.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     */
    public void goBackToBegining()
    {
        flashPanel.rewind();
    }

    /**
     * Select and set the flash movie background color.
     */
    public void backgroundAction(Color c)
    {
        flashPanel.setBackground(c);
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to loop or not.
     */
    void setLoop(boolean loop) {
        flashPanel.setLoop(loop);
    }


    /**
     * Define some buttons to demonstrate JFlashPlayer functionality
     */
    void createButtons() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        playButton = new JButton("Play");
        playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                play();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(playButton);
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Pause");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                stop();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(stopButton);
        backButton = new JButton("Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                goBackToBegining();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(backButton);
        forwardButton = new JButton("Forward");
        forwardButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                forward();
            }
        });
        //buttonPanel.add(forwardButton);
        rewindButton = new JButton("Rewind");
        rewindButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                rewind();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(rewindButton);

        loopCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Loop");
        loopCheckBox.setSelected(true);
        loopCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                setLoop(loopCheckBox.isSelected());
            }
        });

        progressBar.setVisible(true);

        buttonPanel.add(progressBar);

        for (int i = 0; i  screenSize.height) {
            frameSize.height = screenSize.height;
        }
        if (frameSize.width > screenSize.width) {
            frameSize.width = screenSize.width;
        }
        //this.setLocation((screenSize.width - frameSize.width) / 2,
        //      (screenSize.height - frameSize.height) / 2);
        this.setVisible(true);
        //this.toFront();
    }



    @Override
    protected void createProperties()
    {
        properties = new FlashPlayer_Prop(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void action(Enum a)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Enum convertStringToActionEnumValue(String in) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void build(HashMap theDictionary, String filePath, String DataSource, ArrayList actions)
    {
        if(DataSource.equals(DataTypeEnum.url.toString()))
            {
                createFlashPanel((String) theDictionary.get("Path"));
                setDataSource(DataTypeEnum.url);
            }
            else
            {
                String theFile = XMLUtilities.parseFilePath(filePath) + File.separator + (String) theDictionary.get("Path");
                createFlashPanel(new File(theFile));
                setDataSource(DataTypeEnum.file);
            }
        playOnStart = Boolean.parseBoolean(theDictionary.get("PlayOnStart"));
        loop = Boolean.parseBoolean(theDictionary.get("Loop"));
        //add actions to the component
        setActions(XMLUtilities.getActions(this, actions));
    }

    @Override
    public Element extractData(Document dom)
    {
        setData("PlayOnStart",Boolean.toString(playOnStart));
        setData("Loop", Boolean.toString(loop));
        return super.extractData(dom);
    }

    @Override
    public File[] extractFiles(String filePath)
    {
        File retVal = new File(getData("Path"));
        if(retVal == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        setData("Path","files" + File.separator + retVal.getName());
        return new File[]{retVal};
    }

    @Override
    public void drag(File[] theFiles)
    {
     //if they dragged a one file in
        if(theFiles.length == 1)
        {
            //try and set it as the image of this component
            setMovie(new File(theFiles[0].getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        //they dragged multiple files in
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < theFiles.length; i++)
            {
                int location = (i * 5) % mainWindow.getComponentContentPane().getHeight();

                FlashPlayer temp = new FlashPlayer(location,location , mainWindow);
                temp.createFlashPanel(new File(theFiles[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                mainWindow.getCurrPage().addComponent(temp);
                mainWindow.getCurrPage().loadPage();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BCFrame copy(int x, int y) {
        try
        {
            FlashPlayer clone = new FlashPlayer(x,y,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),mainWindow);
            clone.setTitleBarVisible(this.isTitleBarRemoved());
            clone.setActions(this.getActions());
            if(dataSource == dataSource.file)
            {
                clone.setMovie(new File(this.getData("Path")));
            }
            else
            {
                clone.setMovie(this.getData("Path"));
            }
            clone.setPlayOnStart(isPlayOnStart());
            clone.setIsLoop(isLoop());
            return clone;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LogRunner.dialogMessage(this.getClass(),"Cant clone this compoenent");

        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Thread to poll the current frame of the flash movie to be displayed
     */
    class FrameMonitorThread extends Thread {

        FlashPanel flashPanel;

        FrameMonitorThread(FlashPanel fp) {
            flashPanel = fp;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (flashPanel != null) {
                    final long currentFrame = flashPanel.getCurrentFrame();
                    final long totalFrames = flashPanel.getTotalFrames();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            double cf = currentFrame;
                            double tf = totalFrames;
                            double result = cf/tf;
                            int percent = (int)(100 * result);
                            try{progressBar.setValue(percent);}catch(Exception e){}
                            currentFrameLabel.setText("Frame: " + currentFrame + "/" + totalFrames);

                        }
                    });
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whterer the dlls that flash player needs are in their correct spot
     * @return True if all the dlls could be found, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean checkDlls()
    {
        String systemFolder = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\";
        String [] dlls = new String[]{"atl2k.dll","atl98.dll","jflash.dll"};
        for(String x : dlls)
        {
            if(!new File(systemFolder + x).exists())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to embed a web browser, and let that load Flash Player.

See: [Embed a web browser within a java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943927/embed-a-web-browser-within-a-java-application)