# Flash game inside java application

Tags: java, flash, flash-cs5.5

I would like to put a flash game i made with CS.5 (it was exported to a .swf) into a java application. From research i found some ways to to it might be using a embedded web browser or some kind of a flash player:

[Embed .swf file to my Jframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275174/embed-swf-file-to-my-jframe)

[Embed a web browser within a java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943927/embed-a-web-browser-within-a-java-application)

But is this the best way to do it and will it keep the interactivity (ie. the game). It will also fit exactly so if a embedded web browser showed back/front/url/etc. buttons then i can't use it

So whats the best way to do this? And will a flash player inside the java application keep the interactivity (the game working the same as it would in a web browser or in the flash player application)?

Comment: I tried to use http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/ but i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You can used the swf COM API ExternalInterface.call() to communicate with the swf applcaition.

But it only support action script 3 and later.

Comment: my game is made with actionscript 3, how can i do that?

Comment: I don't use swing, I use swt. But swf api is the same one.

Comment: so how do i do it? Or do you have a link to somewhere that will explain how to do it?

Comment: I look at the JFlashPlayer API, it only supports FSCommand API, but it's too old to work on ActionScript 3.

Maybe you should find another java api which supports  ExternalInterface.call().

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void callFunction( String function, String params )
    {
        if ( !created )
            return;
        String request = "<invoke name=\""
                + function
                + "\"><arguments><string>"
                + params
                + "</string></arguments></invoke>";
        Variant[] args = new Variant[1];
        args[0] = new Variant( request );
        flashObject.invokeNoReply( DISPID_CALLFUNCTION, args );
}
```

This is a swt swf call function implements.

You can implement a swf container, it's very easy. Some JNI jars such as JNative, JNA can help you.

I implement a win32 library swt-win32-extension.jar, it contains a custom swf container, but it can't be used by swing.

Comment: A good news. JFlashPlayer2.2 support the ExternalInterface.call().

http://www.brothersoft.com/jpackages-jflashplayer-77667.html

Comment: I found it in a zip here http://www.fileol.com/developer-tools/jpackages-jflashplayer-2.2-free.html will it work with mac as well?

Comment: Maybe you have to implement the function by yourself.

You can use JNA implement it. JNA is a java library, you can use it to call native api by the java code.

Comment: 1. You should study the JNA api, you can download it from : http://jna.java.net/
2. You should study how to wrap a flash in your swing panel.
3. You should study how to use ExternalInterface.call() to communicate with the swf.

I searched it on win32 platform, it's not very hard. I don't know mac clearly.

Comment: how hard is it to convert actionscript 3 to java if it has animation, dynamic text, etc.

Comment: On the mac platform, I think it's not very easy. Almost all of articles about swf wrapping are on the win32 platform, and the dependent jars just support win32 too.