# Unable to play swf file using Transform API

Tags: java, swing, flash

I've tried to play swf file using Transform API [Transform SWF for Java](http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/) but failed. I tired with movie.decodeFromFile(), loadMovieNum() etc.

```
Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.add(Place2.show(2, 3, 2, 2));

//movie.decodeFromFile(new File("test.swf"));
loadMovieNum("test.swf",1);
```

It would be great if I find a sample code for this task.

(Update)

@Josef: You've just copy/paste the code from the website. Actually I wanted to know how to just play a swf file. The code contains other unnecessary things like font, font color etc which is not required to play a swf file.

I think only the following statements are related to playing swf file -

```
Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.add(Place2.show(text.getIdentifier(), layer++, xpos, ypos));
movie.add(ShowFrame.getInstance());
movie.encodeToFile("example.swf");
```

But My question is - should I not need to take a JPlane to add this movie object to play the swf file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of playing a `swf` with transform:

```
int uid = 1;
int layer = 1;

final String str = "The quick, brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
final Color color = WebPalette.BLACK.color();

final String fontName = "Arial";
final int fontSize = 24;
final int fontStyle = java.awt.Font.PLAIN;

// Load the AWT font.
final AWTDecoder fontDecoder = new AWTDecoder();
fontDecoder.read(new java.awt.Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize));
final Font font = fontDecoder.getFonts().get(0);

// Create a table of the characters displayed.
final CharacterSet set = new CharacterSet();
set.add(str);

// Define the font containing only the characters displayed.
DefineFont2 fontDef = font.defineFont(uid++, set.getCharacters());

// Generate the text field used for the button text.
final TextTable textGenerator = new TextTable(fontDef, fontSize * 20);
DefineText2 text = textGenerator.defineText(uid++, str, color);

// Set the screen size to match the text with padding so the
// text does not touch the edge of the screen.
int padding = 1000;
int screenWidth = text.getBounds().getWidth() + padding;
int screenHeight = text.getBounds().getHeight() + padding;

// Position the text in the center of the screen.
final int xpos = padding / 2;
final int ypos = screenHeight / 2;

MovieHeader header = new MovieHeader();
header.setFrameRate(1.0f);
header.setFrameSize(new Bounds(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight));

// Add all the objects together to create the movie.
Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.add(header);
movie.add(new Background(WebPalette.LIGHT_BLUE.color()));
movie.add(fontDef);
movie.add(text);
movie.add(Place2.show(text.getIdentifier(), layer++, xpos, ypos));
movie.add(ShowFrame.getInstance());

movie.encodeToFile("example.swf");
```

---

**EDIT**

[Embed .swf file to JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275174/embed-swf-file-to-my-jframe)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you please show me the way how can I play a swf file in Swing JFrame?

Comment: @user3717550 I added a link to the answer for you :)

Comment: Thanks Josef
Those all seem complex. Could you please show how Transform API can be used in JFrame to embed swf?