# Embed browser in Java based desktop application

Tags: java, browser, embed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)

How can I embed a browser in a Java based desktop application? Can I communicate with the embedded browser directly (not via localhost)... such as loading html text, capturing onclick events, getting form values?

Thanks

Comment: do you want an actual embedded browser, or do you want to programmatically navigate HTML pages?

Comment: May want to checkout https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out Eclipse, it has an embedded browser which is configurable by the user (they support multiple browsers).

you can probably embed their browser even if you use an AWT based application using the AWT_SWT bridge.

this [article](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3644196/Eclipse-Tip-Create-Rich-User-Interfaces-with-the-HTML-Browser-Widget.htm) may help you get started.

Comment: Is there a stand alone version of this?

Answer (score 6):

Swing JEditor pane is able to display HTML.

Check  http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html

Also here in SO is a more detailed answer to this topic:

[**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/java-embedding-a-web-browser-pane**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/java-embedding-a-web-browser-pane)

Comment: The SO link suggests JWebPane, but you suggest JEditor.  I do not think they are the same thing.  Thanks for the links, I will investigate both.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a very primitive browser using [JEditorPane](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html). You can listen to [Hyperlink](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkListener.html) events, but javascript or getting form values isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

[Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) is a Java web browser which can be embedded into Swing applications.

It supports HTML 4, CSS 2, and Javascript, which is more up-to-date compared to the [`JEditorPane`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) which only supports HTML 3.2.

For some ideas on what is possible, the [Lobo Browser API documentation](http://lobobrowser.org/platform-api/index.html) should provide an idea of what is possible to do with Lobo. In particular, the [`org.lobobrowser.gui`](http://lobobrowser.org/platform-api/org/lobobrowser/gui/package-summary.html) has a [`BrowserPanel`](http://lobobrowser.org/platform-api/org/lobobrowser/gui/BrowserPanel.html) class which is a subclass of [`JPanel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), so it can be directly embedded in Swing applications.

For example, the [`BrowserPanel.navigate`](http://lobobrowser.org/platform-api/org/lobobrowser/gui/BrowserPanel.html#navigate(java.lang.String)) method can be used to jump to web pages, and there are many `Listener`s which can capture events which occur in the browser.

Comment: The original Lobo project seems to be dead. Here is a fork: https://sourceforge.net/projects/loboevolution/

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the JWebBrowser from DJ Native Swing: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns

Answer (score 1):

You could try JxBrowser library: http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/features/

For example to embed Mozilla browser into your Java Swing application you just need to do the following code:

```
Browser browser = BrowserFactory.createBrowser(BrowserType.Mozilla);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.add(browser.getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(700, 500);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);

browser.navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: this is not free to use :/

Comment: Update: since 4.0 version JxBrowser integrates with Chromium engine only on all platforms including Mac OS X, Linux and Windows.

Comment: @Vladimir coudl you provide me link for jar file and tutorial for jxBrowser. If you have any tutorial which enable to read epubfile/epublib using jxBrowser please mentioned it.

Comment: @RaviPrajapati JxBrowser JARs you can download from https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser On this web page you can find links on JxBrowser documentation and examples.