# Use Internet Explorer as the embedded browser in a Netbeans RCP app

Tags: netbeans-platform, jxbrowser, embedded-browser

Related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279337/webkit-browser-in-java-app-on-multiple-platforms). Is there any way to embed the system default browser rendering engine in a Netbeans RCP application? For example, on Windows I want IE system default to launch in the embedded browser. It seems easier to do in a C# .net app since we have the [webbrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) control in the .net framework. Including controlling [compatibility options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility.aspx).

I think JxBrowser is quite an expensive solution for just including IE (instead of the JDK default webkit) and people have still reported negative experiences.

Answer (score 0):

[JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) doesn't support MS IE engine anymore. Now, it integrates with Chromium engine only, so you can embed Chromium engine into your Java Swing/JavaFX application.

If you need to integrate with MS IE engine only, then I recommend that you take a look at [JExplorer](https://www.teamdev.com/jexplorer) library. This library allows embedding MS IE WebBrowser control into Java Swing application.