# Dislplaying HTML/CSS in Java GUI

Tags: java, html, css, desktop-application

This is the html I would like to display:
http://boba.dyndns-server.com/Degrees/Art_History_Track_BA.html

I would also like to display this [google calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=groupboba@gmail.com&ctz=America/New_York) as well. (but this link is not a priority)

I have looked into the [DJProject](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) and it appears to require win32 computer, however I would like the program to work on mac and windows. If I am wrong about DJProject, could you please explain me how to implement their [Simple Example](http://djproject.cvs.sourceforge.net/%2acheckout%2a/djproject/DJNativeSwing-SWTDemo/src/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/demo/examples/webbrowser/SimpleWebBrowserExample.java?pathrev=R-0_9_8) using a Eclipse on a Mac.

My goal is to embed the link into a JScrollPanel, with as little overhead as possible.
Thanks for any and all suggestions.

**JEditor Pane can display html, but not html with css in the htmls.

***If you know of away to remove css, I would like to consider that as well

**** The htmls I want to display were generated by a pdf converter.

Comment: Is this for a desktop GUI or for an applet in a browser?

Comment: @Seteven Feldman - I'm goign to remove the [applet] tag then ;)

Comment: Why would you roll back an obvious typo fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SWT Browser directly :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setUrl("http://printf.ru/");
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

For customization : http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/ 
A full tutorial : http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about CSS, but HTML can be used in Java Swing components: see [The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

The Google Calendar would probably require the use of the [Google Calendar Client Library](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-java.html).

Comment: Swing does support some CSS, but not the CSS in the html pages.
Google Calendar Client Library is on how to interact with a calendar, not display it.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed a JWebPane into your application.

See this post for more information on this approach.

[Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)