# How would I be able to open an URL in the same window in java?

Tags: java, url

This is my current code for the open URL part. How can I modify it so it always opens in the same browser window? This is not javascript.

```
    try{
        String url = "www.google.ca"+sn;

        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}

    }
```

This function is called many times where sn is a random new page on google. How can i replace the current page it opens?

Comment: *"... where sn is a random new page on google"* - And the user really wants to see random pages from Google?  How bizarre!

Comment: It was just an example. Iunno

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no general, portable, way to do this.  Depending on the browser and the platform, you *may be able to* do non-portable things to tell an existing browser instance to open a different page.  However, the standard Java APIs don't support this.  (For a start, it may not be technically implementable for some browsers / platforms.)

Another approach might be to use an embedded Java browser; see [Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)

Comment: Also, If I downloaded the JWebEngine, how would i be able to do it..if possible