# Extract image id with Jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to extract a specific captcha image id using api Jsoup, the html image tag is like :

`<img id="wlspispHIPBimg03256465465dsd5456" style="display: inline; width: 200px; height: 100px;" aria-hidden="true" src="https://users/hip/data/rnd=435cb60d0a6b63ef4">`

This is my code to obtain the attribute `id="wlspispHIPBimg03256465465dsd5456"`:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=614866&clcid")
                .timeout(0).get();

Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)]");
for (Element image : images) {
    System.out.println(image.attr("id"));
}
```

The problem is that i can't get the id of captcha image

Comment: This code works fine for me. Please [edit] your question and post [short but complete example which will let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Also `doc.select("img[src~=(?i)");` is same as `doc.select("img[src]");` since `(?i)` is just flag to make used regex case-insensitive but there is no regex there to begin with and your selector wasn't even closed with `]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pshemo, i also tried to use img[^id="wlspispHIPBimg"] but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to find something in the html that discriminates the img tag of any other tag in the document. From your posted code that is can't be deduced, so i use my imagination here:

```
Element imageEl = doc.select("img[scr*=rnd]").first();
```

This exploits that the source of the image contains "rnd" in it path. To get the best solution you must look yourself. Also it helps a lot if you learn the CSS selectors of Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply can't accomplish this using only Jsoup, the DOM is modified at runtime with javascript and jsoup simply does not execute it.

View also this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488872/page-content-is-loaded-with-javascript-and-jsoup-doesnt-see-it).