# Jsoup.body() returns empty body

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, web, jsoup

I am trying to get HTML's body content but it returns me an empty body only to this specific site, what can it be?

```
Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("http://givatram.ort.org.il/%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA/")
            .userAgent(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
            .timeout(0).followRedirects(true).execute().parse();
    Elements titles = doc.select(".entrytitle");

    System.out.println(doc.body());
```

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your problem. If I check the entire document with `System.out.println(doc)` then I can see that there is a script in the head tag, which indicates that it *does* connect to the site. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7489380/6816200)  Jsoup is only a pure HTML parser and doesn't execute Javascript. Maybe the content of the site is loaded via Javascript and that is why the body is empty?

**Edit 1:**

I could verify this. If I use [ui4j](https://github.com/webfolderio/ui4j), a small wrapper for the JavaFx Browser, I can see the body:

```
BrowserEngine browser = BrowserFactory.getWebKit();
Page page = browser.navigate("http://givatram.ort.org.il/%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA/");
System.out.println(page.getDocument().getBody());
```

So it seems like what you are trying to do is unfortunately not possible with JSoup.