# How to read datatable from a link in JavaServlet?

Tags: java, servlets, bufferedreader

I'm working in a University project. My situation is very simple, I think: I take data from a table in local machine with this code on my Servlet:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\fileName.csv")));
```

Now, I want to take a step beyond: I want to read data from an external link in which there is a table (I created the link with Google Fusion Tables and it contains the identical data of my 'fileName.csv' in local machine).
How can I solve this?
Thank so so much to who will answer!

Answer (score 0):

Google has an [official API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/getting_started) for its Fusion Tables that you can use.

Apart from that I think [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is the best tool to parse html documents (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488872/page-content-is-loaded-with-javascript-and-jsoup-doesnt-see-it) if you cannot get page data directly with jsoup). If you know basic HTML and CSS then it's very easy to use this library.

Comment: I am new in Java, so the somehow is very difficult to apply for me :/ I take the content of the table and put it in an object, then I visualize it on jsp. Can you be more accurate, please. Thanks so much!

Comment: By "table" you mean html <table> element?

Comment: In Servlet I take the data as an object, in jsp I take the object and I put it in a <table>

Comment: Could you please share URL of your google fusion table?

Comment: Can I send you the code for email or something? Here is the URL https://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&t=TABLE&q=select+col0,+col1,+col2+from+1MpxEn5AlnBGokIBt9GuBn1VrqzLKO6qYoIoJldN-&containerId=googft-gviz-canvas

Comment: Google offers its api that you can make use of (unfortunately I don't have any experience in it and it seems that using that api requires some effort)