# Java - How do I access a child of Div using JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

In the below example I'm trying to access each 'div.searchRcrd', the childs of 'content-area', but I'm lost in how I go about accessing them. I made a quick program trying to highlight my issue, using print statements to show it's not accessing the correct information. I've tried changing my doc.select to other variations such as ("div.content-area div.searchRcrd") with no avail.

I've looked all over stackoverflow before posting here, but I'm completely lost on this one. As always I appreciate any advice on where I'm going wrong on this.

```
public class Main 
{
    // retrieve page source code
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://uk.webuy.com/search/?categoryIds=1040&view=list&inStock=1").get();

    // find all of the div rows in content-area
    org.jsoup.select.Elements rows = doc.select("div.content-area div");
    ListIterator<Element> itr = rows.listIterator();

    // loop over each row
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
    {
        Element row = itr.next();
        System.out.println("Test"); //Prints out 5 times instead of the multiple I expect

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the reason you need to print the whole `HTML` page `JSOUP` has loaded. You will notice that page looks different in web browser and what `JSOUP` sees. It looks like you need to enable `JavaScript` somehow and it will load the page properly using `Ajax` requests.

Please, take a look on below link

1. [Page content is loaded with JavaScript and Jsoup doesn't see it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488872/page-content-is-loaded-with-javascript-and-jsoup-doesnt-see-it)

Edit:
But there is even better solution. You can notice that data are loaded in separate call. For example, browser does one extra call to show page you provided:

> https://wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io/v3/boxes?inStock=1&categoryIds=[1040]&firstRecord=1&count=50&sortBy=relevance&sortOrder=desc

Try to download it and use `Jackson` library to parse it.

Comment: Great answer, you highlighted many things I didn't realize were a factor in extracting html information. Thanks for the links too I'll definitely look more into it from here :)