# Parsing data from HTML with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm learning Java and I'm using jsoup to parse data from www.livescore.com in order to get all football results into my app, but I can't see them in the source code because everything is encrypted, I think. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Most likely, the site relies on Javascript to generate the scores. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7488872/4125191) for example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsoup/info

Answer (score 1):

If you disable Javascript on www.livescore.com it asks if you want to go to the legacy website which is - https://www.livescores.com. Their legacy website doesn't seem to have the encryption in place which you should be able to use with Jsoup and parse the html.