# Jsoup doesnt support JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin, web-scraping, jsoup

I have problem with login to google account, returned content by Jsoup

`Google Accounts Couldn't sign you in The browser you're using doesn't support JavaScript, or has JavaScript turned off. To keep your Google Account secure, try signing in on a browser that has JavaScript turned on. Learn more Google Privacy Terms`

```
    val loginUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth"

    val loginPage = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl)
        .header("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute()

    val rPage = Jsoup.connect("$loginUrl?$loginContent").cookies(cookies)
        .header("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
        .post()

    println(rPage.text())
```

Some ideas to fix?

Comment: Try to solve your problem with [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way with Jsoup. You can use an embedded browser for your case.

See following question for more details:

[Page content is loaded with JavaScript and Jsoup doesn't see it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488872/page-content-is-loaded-with-javascript-and-jsoup-doesnt-see-it)