# Jsoup doesn't fully fetch the raw html code

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to fetch some lyrics from genius.com (i know they have an api.I am doing it manually.) but i dont seem to be getting the same html string everytime.In fact i put the code below in a for loop and it seems to be working only %50 of the time.

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Fetch_lyrics {
    public static void testing() {
        try {

            String urll = "https://genius.com/In-mourning-debris-lyrics";;
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urll).maxBodySize(0).get();
            String text = doc.select("p").first().toString();
            System.out.println(text);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I printed the raw html via doc variable and it seems that around 50% of the time the raw html string doesn't have the `<p>` class(idk if it's called class or something else) that contains the lyrics.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related: [Page content is loaded with JavaScript and Jsoup doesn't see it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7488872)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like genius.com returns different content for new users. I got two different contents when I came for the first time and when I cleared cookies in a browser (Chrome) and went again.

I recommend you add two selectors to get the information you need.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;

class Outer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String urll = "https://genius.com/In-mourning-debris-lyrics";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urll).maxBodySize(0).get();
            Element first = doc.selectFirst("p");
            if (first == null) {
                first = doc.selectFirst("div[class^=Lyrics__Container]");
            }
            if (first != null) {
                System.out.println(first.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```