# Jsoup select method returning null when passed identical query string that returns results in google inspect element

Tags: java, jsoup

```java
Document upgradedItem = Jsoup.connect("https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Items").get();
Elements element = upgradedItem.select("#mw-content-text > div > div:nth-child(4)");
```

If you go to the site and paste in the css selector, It will return 1 result, however JSoup returns null.

Comment: It looks like the page downloaded by Jsoup is not the same as the page you view in the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page content is loaded with JavaScript and Jsoup doesn't see it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488872/page-content-is-loaded-with-javascript-and-jsoup-doesnt-see-it)