# Jsoup webscraping to find game odds data

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, data-extraction

I've been trying to create a program in Java that can catch the odds of a game from a sportsbook like FanDuel but I've been running into a lot of problems. When I print the html for the site I dont get the entire html for the site so Im unable to go into the divs and retrieve the actual data I want.
I used the Url https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/ . If I try and run a method like Elements element = doc.getElementByID("root"); to get the data inside that div the rest of the data in that div will not appear. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFYuu.png). I specifically would just like to get the moneyline data for each game if anyone can help that would be great

```
public class ExtractSportsBookData {
    public static void extractData(String url){
        try{
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            String html = doc.html();
            System.out.println(html);
            
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gy0l.png)
If you look at the image inside the li tags is where the data is stored for the moneylines for each game but I cannot seem to find a way to extract that data using Jsoup

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtractSportsBookData.extractData("https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/");

    }
}


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.SyncFailedException;

public class ExtractSportsBookData {
    public static void extractData(String url){
        try{
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            String html = doc.html();
            //System.out.println(html);
            Elements element = doc.getElementsByClass("jo jp fk fe jy jz bs");
            System.out.println(element.isEmpty());

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVF2c.png)
The result I receive from this is true meaning that the element is empty which is not what I want. Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: It’s unlikely to be a static site.

Comment: @DaveNewton shouldn't I still be able to extract the html data in the moment?

Comment: Not if it’s generated dynamically, no; IIRC JSoup doesn’t do JS. For that you need to drive a full, headless or not, or reverse engineer their back end requests. *Noting that either are almost certainly against their TOS (but I’m guessing).*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page content is loaded with JavaScript and Jsoup doesn't see it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488872/page-content-is-loaded-with-javascript-and-jsoup-doesnt-see-it)