# Inputting a delay on Jsoup when encountering JSON

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to put together a Jsoup app that pulls four factors data from the following site:

https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/four-factors

I ran into a problem recently where Jsoup was pulling blanks and after some searching I found out that it's because the page loads the data through JSON which has a delay, so when Jsoup connects and goes to extract the data there's nothing there.

My question is, is there a way to delay Jsoup from pulling the data until the page is properly loaded?

My code is below. Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class Comparison {
    
    public void loadTeams() {
    
        try {
                ArrayList<Team> NBA = new ArrayList<Team>(30);
                Document nba = Jsoup.connect("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/four-factors").get();         
                Elements team = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("field", "TEAM_NAME");
                Elements shooting = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("field" , "EFG_PCT");
                Elements turnovers = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("field" , "TM_TOV_PCT");
                Elements rebounds = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("field" , "OREB_PCT");
                Elements freethrows = nba.getElementsByAttributeValue("field" , "FTA_PCTS");
            
                for (int i = 0; i < team.size(); i++) {
                    String name = team.get(i).text();
                    double shootingScore = Double.parseDouble(shooting.get(i).text());
                    double turnoversScore = Double.parseDouble(turnovers.get(i).text());    
                    double reboundsScore = Double.parseDouble(rebounds.get(i).text());  
                    double freethrowsScore = Double.parseDouble(freethrows.get(i).text());  
                    NBA.add(new Team(name, shootingScore, turnoversScore, reboundsScore, freethrowsScore));
                }
            //for testing//
            for(int i=0; i<NBA.size(); i++) {
                System.out.print(NBA.getClass());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could this question be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488872/page-content-is-loaded-with-javascript-and-jsoup-doesnt-see-it