# Facebook OAuth login with Java (desktop only)

Tags: java, facebook, desktop-application, oauth-2.0

How do I login into Facebook and get a accesstoken in Java with a desktop application only?

I found a api http://restfb.com that lets you call methods but you have to get the token yourself. So is there a way to do this using only a desktop app? Maybe embed a browser to a window popup?

I already know the process in getting a token explained here http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens so my question doesnt involve that. I need a way for the user to login into facebook using some kind of GUI.

Comment: What about [Leeloo](http://leeloo.smartam.net/)?

Comment: im trying to run the demo they provide https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBER/OAuth+2.0+Client+Demo and requires that i use javax.servlet, which i dont seem to have :(

Answer (score 0):

As in the facebook document

> Our OAuth 2.0 implementation does not include explicit support for application built for desktop operating systems. However, if your app can embed a web browser (most desktop frameworks such as .NET, AIR and Cocoa support embedding browsers), you can use the client-side flow with one modification: a specific redirect_uri. Rather than requiring desktop apps to host a web server and populate the Site URL in the Developer App, we provide a specific URL you can use with desktop apps: https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html.

I think you are right about embed web browser.

And I suggest you to move to Graph API instead of Rest, Because It's deprecating.

[see more abount Facebook Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

[Deprecating the REST API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/)

Comment: any idea of how to embed a web browser in java using desktop only?

Comment: There is question about this here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)