# Display HTML/Javascript based webpage in Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, html, jxbrowser

I am looking for a way to integrate a webpage into my java swing based application. The page uses HTML and absolutely requires Javascript to be enabled to function properly, so I won't be able to use something like a JEditorPane.

I've heard rumors of a JWebPane, but can't find any documentation on the subject. I also have no ability to afford something like JxBrowser, even though that looks like something that would work perfectly for what I want to do.

Does anyone have any advice on how I could display a webpage in a Java app without dropping more than a grand?

Comment: Are you absolutely tied to Java and in particular the Java Swing library?

Comment: I'm not tied to swing, but I would need to be able to add whatever component could be used to a JPanel

Comment: `"I'm not tied to swing, but I would need to be able to add whatever component could be used to a JPanel"` -- <confused>That sure sounds like Swing to me.</confused>

Comment: I meant it to mean that I could use AWT components as well, but I could have been clearer. This is a small-ish part of a much larger program that is already built, so I'm afraid I'm kind of stuck to Swing/Java.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java