# Embed a browser in Libgdx

Tags: java, facebook, browser, embed, libgdx

I am writing a cross platform app(PC, iOS, Android) in Java. I would like to integrate facebook into this app. I have been trying to find a uniform method to login, since it is a cross-platform applicaiton. So I have been following [Facebook's manual login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/) to try an approach that will work on each platform. I am using [restFB](http://restfb.com/#download) to handle the interaction with Facebook after I get the access token from the user. That last bit is causing difficulties. It seems the only way for me to get the users access token is to have them sign in from an embedded browser.

Now I have looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java), but the problem is that Libgdx is not compatible with JavaFX. So my question is: Is there a relatively simple way to embed a web browser into an app that is built via Libgdx?

Comment: No, there is no simple solution. You have to write platform specific code to start a real browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is: Is there a relatively simple way to embed a web browser into an app that is built via Libgdx?

**Nop**