# Is HTML rendering possible in libgdx (or, what is the best practice to create a help screen)?

Tags: libgdx

I want to create a help `screen` for my game. This screen contains text and pictures that describe the game.

One option is to create a `stage` and add a `table` to it that will define the position of the different `labels` and `images`. However, this option seems to be "unnatural", limited when it comes to format options, and a potential headache when it comes to code maintenance.

The content of the screen is static which makes it a good candidate for an HTML document. My idea is to create the help screen document in HTML and then have it rendered inside my help screen. My question is, is this possible in libgdx? If not, what other way would I have to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is not possible to embed a browser in your LibGDX app (as nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992483/4691862)), you could either [link to an external website](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=670) in the device's browser or use the [libgdx-stagebuilder](https://github.com/peakgames/libgdx-stagebuilder) to build up the Scene2D stage using XML. Or you just stick to the normal LibGDX way. Unfortunately, I don't see any other option than those.

Comment: I was unaware of `stagebuilder`. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported in libGDX as of yet, but it should be possible using platform specific code. How you do it will vary from platform to platform, so I can't tell you exactly what to look up, but android has something called webview you might want to look at.