# WebBrowser in Java app

Tags: java, swing, browser

I am trying to embed A functional web browser in my java app.

I tried [jBrowser]<sup>1</sup> but first it is for 32 bits platform and when I try in 32 bits it don't work, shows this message:

`"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\xulrunner\xulrunner\xulrunner\javaxpcomglue.dll: Can't find dependent libraries"`

I tried using `setXulRunnerPath(new File("d://xulrunner"))` with latest. I tried with previous version and dont work anyway, but instead I found this [advice]<sup>2</sup>. I saw the swt browser works but  I need my application in swing.

My question: Is there is some component to acomplish this? Thank you in advance for any help.

<sup>1</sup>: https://code.google.com/p/jbrowser/
  <sup>2</sup>: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaXPCOM/Embedding_Mozilla_in_a_Java_Application_using_JavaXPCOM

Comment: Would `Desktop#browse()` be an alternative?

Comment: You could try Webkit-based WebView which is built-in into JDK 7+.

Comment: If you are using 32 bit native code, you need to be running within a 32 bit version of Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody else has asked this question on here for embedding a web browser into a java application so an answer their may help.

[Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)