# How do I import flash player into java? I have created a browser and I want it to run flash, but it won't

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash

How do I import flash player into java? I have created a browser and I want it to run flash, but I don't know how to go about doing so. Is this possible? Will I have to compile it first - before I can install flash? Or is there a way to kind of import or add flash into the actual source so that I'm able to run flash using my web browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most browsers Adobe Flash runs as a plugin. This means that the browser runs the Flash player as a separate program, gives it some room on the screen to display itself, and passes inputs and handles outputs.

You will almost certanly need a licence from Adobe if you want to embed the flash plugin into your software, and you'll probably need to think about cross platform issues. [Adobe's website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer.html) has a bunch more info.